# MySQL JOIN and SUBSELECT CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, database

As a developer, I know a good DB guy is worth their weight in gold. I often find myself using seriously inefficient ways to tackle non critical problems, but in this current case, I need speed over 'just make it work'. I won't even show what I've done so far as it's so embarrassing, but lets just say that I had sub queries within my main PHP while loop. Sorry.

I have several tables that I need to join together for a json request to an indexing engine (Apache SOLR).

```
tbl_contacts
+----+--------------+---------------+
| ID | FirstName    | LastName      |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 1  | Joe          | Blogs         |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 2  | Jane         | Baker         |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 3  | John         | Doe           |
+----+--------------+---------------+


tbl_attributes_map
+----+--------------+---------------+
| ID | ContactID    | AttributeID   |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 1  | 1            | 1             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 2  | 1            | 3             |
+----+--------------+---------------+
| 3  | 2            | 2             |
+----+--------------+---------------+


tbl_attributes
+----+---------------+---------------+
| ID | AttributeType | Attribute     |
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | Lower         | Shoe          |
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 2  | Upper         | T-Shirt       |
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 3  | Upper         | Vest          |
+----+---------------+---------------+


tbl_notes
+----+---------------+---------------+
| ID | ContactID     | Note          |
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 1  | 1             | Big feet      |
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 2  | 2             | Showoff       |
+----+---------------+---------------+
| 3  | 2             | Sweaty        |
+----+---------------+---------------+

tbl_appointment
+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| ID | ContactID     | Location      | TimeFrom           | TimeTo            |
+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 1             | Big Ben       | 2015-12-16 08:00:00|2015-12-16 08:30:00|
+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 2             | London        | 2015-12-17 10:00:00|2015-12-17 11:00:00|
+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | 2             | New York      | 2015-12-16 12:00:00|2015-12-16 12:30:00|
+----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I need to run a query which essentially allows me to print an array structure such as:

```
Array(
   [FirstName]   => Joe
   [LastName]    => Blogs
   [Upper]       => Array(
                       Vest
                    )
   [Lower]       => Array(
                       Shoe
                    )
   [Notes]       => Array(
                       Big Feet
                    )
   [Location]    => Array(
                       Big Ben
                    )
   [ApptFrom]    => Array(
                       2015-12-16 08:00:00
                    )
   [ApptTo]      => Array(
                       2015-12-16 08:30:00
                    )
```

If I can get to a stage where I can run a query to get the following output, I can run a delimiter to implode on the fields that I need to build an array for. EG:

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| ID | FirstName  | LastName  | Upper   | Lower   | Notes           | Location          | ApptFrom                                | ApptTo                                  |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 2  | Jane       | Baker     | T-Shirt |         | Show off,Sweaty | London,New York   | 2015-12-17 10:00:00,2015-12-16 12:00:00 | 2015-12-17 11:00:00,2015-12-16 12:30:00 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

My script currently works, but at a high performance penalty. It takes around 3 hours to churn through 80,000 contacts :-/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should probably show us your script. 80,000 shouldn't be a problem for SQL. Plus, normalizing it would improve its performance.

Comment: joins, group by, and use group_concat() to produce the comma separated values in a single field.

Comment: To my way of thinking, there is no problem in MySQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the answer - especially so where a presentation layer is provided. Anyway, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly similar situation when I start indexing Elasticsearch (use Apache Lucene as SOLR) 50 million of data, now it only take me couple of hours I think what you can do are following:

1. put explain on your query to see if your query are using the proper index
2. try to use more sub select instead of join because mysql have problem to select with index for million of data (you can use force index maybe)
3. start muti-thread to do  your indexing